# Which cases should be used _redirect() or _forward() in Zend Framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, http

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between redirect and forward in Zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551238/what-is-the-difference-between-redirect-and-forward-in-zend-framework)

Please provide real and practical examples.

Comment: definite duplicate of [What is the difference between redirect and forward in Zend framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551238/what-is-the-difference-between-redirect-and-forward-in-zend-framework). please use the search function before asking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

both are totally different things _forward is internal redirection of zf , i.e practically user browser even dont know about this redirection , but inside zf all the hooks after predispatch gets invoked . Whereas in _redirect case user browser takes control of redirection and make second request hence everthing inside zf gets invoked once age (bootstrap , routing etc) .

clearely _forward is less resource intensive then _redirect but if you need the code inside bootstrap to be called (in case you have made changes in config and want it to reload) then you should do _redirect .